# Onclick function assignment not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am writing a simple game and want to add a `click` event to the `body` element. But the script below does not work. Is there anything I can change to make it work?

```
var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
theBody.addEventListener("click", gameOver);
theBody.onclick = gameOver();
function gameOver() {
    alert("Game Over!");
}
```

Comment: `theBody.onclick = gameOver;` - get rid of the `()` because that means that you're *calling* the function.

Comment: also `var theBody = document.body;` is a little simpler :)

Comment: `theBody.onclick = gameOver();` is not needed..Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/muevbeqm/

Comment: @Pointy, I have edited that..What I meant was `theBody.addEventListener("click", gameOver);  
theBody.onclick = gameOver();` both the lines does the same operation and later one is written inappropriately..

Comment: @Pointy, What is the point of having 2 event listener having same callback on the same element ?

Comment: This game seems sad. How do you win? ;)

Comment: @RayonDabre ah, well that's certainly a good point. I retract my statement because you're 100% correct, and I offer my apologies.

Comment: @Pointy, he he.. May be I need to work on framing sentences :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - onclick event getting called automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101899/javascript-onclick-event-getting-called-automatically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Try this:

document.getElementsByTagName("body ").addEventListener("click", function(){
    gameOver();
});
function gameOver() {
    alert("Game Over!");
}
```

Comment: @susansecret [No, this absolutely does not work...](http://jsfiddle.net/5wvb654u/) It throws the error `document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function` because you can't assign an event listener to an array. It's also terrible style because you're creating a function just to call another function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", gameOver);
```

Or this:

```
document.body.onclick = gameOver; // no brackets
```

Not both.

Comment: Thank you. I removed some code and now the code is as below. But it still doesn't work... 
    theBody.addEventListener("click", gameOver);  
    function gameOver() {  
 alert("Game Over!");  
    }