# why validate function invoke after page refresh and nothing happen on click

Tags: javascript

```
var asign = function(id){

 return document.getElementById(id) ;
 } ;

var f_name = asign('fname').value ;

 var validate = function (a) {
this.a = a ;
    if(!a){
        alert("Somthing is require");
    }  else if(a.length<6){
        alert("characters should be minimum 6") ;
    }
}  


 asign('submit').addEventListener('click',validate(f_name),false) ;
```

validate function invoke in page refresh and after click the button nothing happen validate function nothing happen

Comment: Related: [`onclick` event getting called automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10101899/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass reference to function as a argument in `addEventListener` but not call it,

**1**.you can wrap your code to function like this

```
asign('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
  validate();
}, false);
```

**2**.or use `.bind`

```
asign('submit').addEventListener('click', validate.bind({}), false);
```

Example

```js
var asign = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

var validate = function () {
  var a = asign('fname').value;
  
  if (!a) {
    alert("Somthing is require");
  } else if (a.length < 6) {
    alert("characters should be minimum 6");
  }
}


asign('submit').addEventListener('click', validate.bind({}), false);
```

```html
<input id="fname">
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: #impressed with the all varieties of `.bind()`. Thanks!